# Mistake with DKIM 9936A801ED08: no signing table match for using wildcard

Tags: centos7, dkim, opendkim

I have configured DKIM to be used with wildcards in SigningTable (Centos7)

But it gives me an error, and I am not able to see it.

```
Feb 15 08:46:56 monitor01 postfix/submission/smtpd[3374]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb 15 08:46:56 monitor01 postfix/submission/smtpd[3374]: 9936A801ED08: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=abkrim
Feb 15 08:46:56 monitor01 postfix/cleanup[3381]: 9936A801ED08: message-id=<602a26f0.w9SaFG9+Lk6Z+ZTe%abkrim@monitor01.domain.net>
Feb 15 08:46:56 monitor01 opendkim[1003]: 9936A801ED08: no signing table match for 'abkrim@monitor01.domain.net'
Feb 15 08:46:56 monitor01 opendkim[1003]: 9936A801ED08: no signature data
```

#### opendkim.conf

```
PidFile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
Mode    sv
Syslog  yes
SyslogSuccess   yes
LogWhy  yes
UserID  opendkim:opendkim
Socket  inet:8891@localhost
Umask   002
SendReports     yes
SoftwareHeader  yes
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Domain  monitor01.tamainut.net
Selector        default
MinimumKeyBits  1024
KeyTable        refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
OversignHeaders From
SubDomains         no
AutoRestart         yes
AutoRestartRate     10/1M
Background          yes
DNSTimeout          5
SignatureAlgorithm  rsa-sha256
```

#### /etc/opendkim/SigningTable

```
*@monitor01.domain.net default._domainkey.monitor01.domain.net
```

Keys correct in /etc/opendkim/keys/monitor01.domain.net/ and dir permisson correct

```
   193751 4,0K -rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim 1,7K feb 11 07:50 default.private
   193753 4,0K -rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim  501 feb 11 07:50 default.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a CR character in SigningTable file (refile:/etc/opendkim/signing_table).

Check it out, remove the CR character.

Also, make sure that your Mode is set to "sv" (for sign and verify) and not just "v" (verify only, which is the default).

Comment: double before post cr, also file is created and edited in unix system, not windows. Also in file i put content `Mode    sv`